# Why do my website's post-page-load Ajax calls fail in the Facebook In-App Browser?

Tags: ajax, facebook

My website uses Ajax to report the user's progress back to the server while the user stays on the same webpage. This works fine on all browsers except the Facebook In-App Browser (FB IAB). Why?

Answer (score 1):

If your web server uses cookies when processing Ajax requests, you will have the following problem:

After a web page loads, FB IAB doesn't send cookies to the server for Ajax calls. I consider this a bug.

A workaround is to send all required data in the querystring instead.

Comment: John does this occur on iOS and Android? Do you have any other details here?

Comment: @GlenT I reproduced the bug on Android only. I didn't check iOS. My error logs suggest that iOS has the bug too, but I haven't verified that. My error logs also suggest that Android 4, 5, and 6 have the bug and that all Facebook App versions have the bug; the highest Facebook app version I saw in the error logs was 96.

Comment: Thanks for the extra details John. I've seen cookies successfully being sent with my requests when I monitored the traffic between the Android app and our website. However I haven't yet checked the versions (which I'll take a look at now. Have you raised this bug with Facebook? It seems like if we can reproduce it it would be worth raising as this is a pretty big issue.

Comment: @GlenT I have not raised this issue with Facebook -- not a priority for me. I haven't found anyone else experiencing this issue. I have to wonder if it's a real issue. How did you come across this SO post, Glen?

Comment: After a lot of searching hah. For me we're seeing a gap in events triggered from JS vs our server when in the FB app.

Comment: @GlenT We too were seeing gaps in events triggered from JS vs our server, but only with the FB app. Events that occurred while the page loaded were getting recorded. Events that occurred after the page loaded were not getting recorded; instead, errors were being recorded in the error logs. The web logs showed clearly that the FB app wasn't sending cookies with Ajax calls that happened after the page was done loading.